# flex adaptative textinput function of maxchars

Tags: apache-flex, textinput

I want to build a textinput that adapts itself from the maxchars value of its textdisplay.

I tried to override the init function of the component like this:

```
override protected function initializationComplete():void{
   if(this.textDisplay.maxChars != 0){
      this.maxWidth = this.textDisplay.maxChars*10;
      super.initializationComplete();
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. How can I code this?

Comment: You want to build a TextInput that adapts itself **HOW** from the maxchars value of it's textDisplay?  What sort of change are you expecting to see to the TextInput and when should that change occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats already there in s:textinput property named widthInChars 
set that value to maxChars value like this

Im mxml

```
<s:TextInput id="txtName" widthInChars="{txtName.maxChars}" maxChars="23" />
```

In as

```
txtName.widthInChars = txtName.maxChars;
```

Try this
I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm. I just have a warning message:
"Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to maxChars"